# Proof of factorial inequality concerning fractions

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, summation, factorial

I'm having trouble with a proof, with the case $n>2$.

THEOREM: For every natural number $n∈N$ where $n≠2$, $∑_{i=1}^ni≤n!$

Let us simplify the statement.

$$\begin{alignat*}{2}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}&≤n!\\
\frac{  \frac{n(n+1)}{2}   }{n}&≤\frac{n!}{n}\\
\frac{n+1}{2}&≤(n-1)!\\
\frac{  \frac{n+1}{2}   }{n+1}&≤\frac{(n-1)!}{n+1}\\
\frac{1}{2}&≤\frac{(n-1)!}{n+1}\end{alignat*}$$

Case $n=1$:$\ldots$

Case $n=2$:$\ldots$

Case $n>2$:

To represent a natural number n>2, one can take another natural number $k$ and add two to it. Then:
$$\frac{1}{2}≤\frac{(k+1)!}{(k+3)}$$

$\ldots?$

---

Now, I'm stuck for the last case. I have no idea where to go from there. Any hints?

Comment: How is $\frac12 \le \frac{1!}{2+1} = \frac13$?!?

Comment: Propositions that involve summation, factorial and phrases like "for every $n \in \mathbb N$" can often be proved using induction.

Comment: @AlexR Excluding the case $n=2$, as stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case $n=1$ is just $1\le 1$. The case $n=2$ is excluded from the theorem, for $n=3$ we get $6\le 6$.

Now proceed by induction: Assuming $n>2$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i = \sum_{i=1}^n i + n + 1 \le n! + n + 1 \stackrel{(\ast)}\le n! (n+1) = (n+1)!$$
In $(\ast)$ we used that $n>2$ so $n+1\le n\cdot n!$ and thus $n! + n+1 \le (n+1)!$

Comment: Do you mind expanding the proof? It is a tad confusing.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien I don't mind at all, if you could tell me wich parts need additional comment, I'll happily add them.

Comment: Thanks. I'm confused with the combined notation of $=$ and $\leq$. Do you mean to say $\sum_{i=1}^n i + n + 1 \le n! + n + 1$, which is in turn less than or equal to $n! (n+1) = (n+1)!$

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Correct. $1\le 1 < 2 = \frac42 \le 3$ would be another valid chain.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative proof (by induction).

---

**First, show that this is true for $n=3$:**

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3}i\leq{3!}$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}i\leq{n!}$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}i=\left(\color{red}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}i}\right)+(n+1)\leq\color{red}{n!}+(n+1)\leq n!\times(n+1)=(n+1)!$$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Comment: $n! + (n+1) \le n! \cdot (n+1)$ is false in general. That's why the $n=2$ case is false.

Comment: @AlexR: Yep, I should have started with $n=3$. Just realized it as you wrote the comment. Thanks :)